# My TODO APP solutions is consistent with OOP?

Tags: c#, rest, oop, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I would like to have your opinions by contribution to these two implementations of a TODO List application as to the respect of the principles of object-oriented programming.

Solution 1 : geting corresponding todoList Objet via TodoListRepository and Add  TodoItem via the getting Object

```
 class TodoItem{
        private readonly string _libele;
        private readonly int _todoListId;
        public string Libele => _libele;
        public TodoItem(int todoListId, string libele)
        {
            _libele = libele;
            _todoListId = todoListId;
        }
}

class TodoList{


        private readonly ICollection<TodoItem> _items;
        private readonly int _id;

        public IReadOnlyList<TodoItem> Items => _items.ToList();


        public void AddItem(string libele)
        {
            _items.Add(new TodoItem(_id, libele));
        }
}
```

```
class TodoListService    {
        private readonly ITodoListRepository _repository;
        private readonly IAppUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public TodoListService(ITodoListRepository repository, IAppUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _repository = repository;
        }



        void AddItemToTodoList(int todoListId, string lebele)
        {
            var todList = _repository.GetTodoListById(todoListId);
            todList.AddItem(lebele);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        }


}
```

Solution 2 Add todoItem via TodoItemRepository witout passing by TodoList Object

```
class TodoItem {
        private readonly string _libele;
        private readonly int _todoListId;
        public string Libele => _libele;
        public TodoItem(int todoListId, string libele)
        {
            _libele = libele;
            _todoListId = todoListId;
        }
}


class TodoList{


        private readonly ICollection<TodoItem> _items;
        private readonly int _id;
        public IReadOnlyList<TodoItem> Items => _items.ToList();


}
```

```
class TodoItemService {
        private readonly ITodoItemRepository _repository;
        private readonly IAppUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
       
 public TodoItemService(ITodoItemRepository repository, IAppUnitOfWork unitOfWork){
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _repository = repository;
        }

        void AddItemToTodoList(int todoListId, string lebele){
            var todoItem = new TodoItem(todoListId, lebele);
            _repository.Add(todoItem);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

}
```

Is solution 1 consistent with OOP. What are the opinions between the two solutions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes `TodoItem` and `TodoList` are fairly simple and have one responsibility ([Single responsibility Principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle)).
And these classes do not have any code that can pollute their  single responsibility. I mean there is no logic for logging or other responsibilities in these classes. So it is okay. [Read another great post about Single Responsibility Principle.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541197/does-the-single-responsibility-principle-work-in-oop/46556381)

But it looks like your code in solution 1 will not save any items as your item will be added to `IReadOnlyList<TodoItem> Items`.

I like that repository has great separation of concerns. I mean that `repository` is here like simple collection of items. We can make analogy with `List<T>`, that
`List<T>` does not have `Save()` method. Responsibility of saving item is delegated to `_unitOfWork`. And this is also great separation of concerns.

```
void AddItemToTodoList(int todoListId, string lebele)
{
    var todoItem = new TodoItem(todoListId, lebele);
    _repository.Add(todoItem);
    _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```