# Class that one of his members is object

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, object-object-mapping

Lets say I have class called `Connection`. One of his members is object that is instance of another class, class `VerificationCode`.

The class `VerificationCode` has 2 members: `code` and `expiresAt`.

Should I keep the `VerificationCode` and associate it with the member, or should I associate the 2 members `code` and `expiresAt` directly to the `Connection` class?

What are the advantages or disadvantages in terms of design/modeling?

Example:

Option 1:

```
Class VerificationCode{
code: string;
expiresAt: number;
}

Class Connection{
a: string;
verificationCode: VerificationCode;
}
```

Option 2:

```
Class Connection{
a: string;
code: string;
expiresAt: number;
}
```

Comment: Is `VerificationCode` a useful abstraction in your codebase? We cannot answer that. Maybe it is, maybe its properties only ever makes sense as part of `Connection` but not standalone.

Comment: Note that the syntax is `class` and not `Class`.  Also note that classes generally require property initialization, which you're not doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is better for me. Because it has:

- great separation of concerns. Now you have just two fields such as `code` and `expiresAt`, but when you will have methods for this variables, then it would be violation of S[ingle Responsibility principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541197/does-the-single-responsibility-principle-work-in-oop) if you will edit `code` and `expiresAt` in class `Connection`
- has high cohesion in classes. Read more [what cohesion is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085285/difference-between-cohesion-and-coupling).